# form that creates page and entry in database

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

Hi everyone I want to create a really simple cms in which once admin login , he can view 6 categories and then click the category in which he wants to add a new page. When he clicks on create new page under any category , he will see predefined fields that he needs to enter like page title , file name (like if he enters adc , then file abc.php will be created) and 4-6 others fields that goes into DB and shows on the page as well(once click on submit). So actually the admin will just be filling a form to create a page and entry in DB . I just want help with algorithm not the coding.

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic content creation in PHP, and is a great starting point for learning PHP. There's two main points you'll be covering: authentication and database relations. You need to authenticate (create a system which stops unauthorised users accessing certain pages), then be able to talk to the database (in order to list and create pages).

There are many, many resources about for learning PHP. Stack Overflow (while great) is unlikely to furnish you with a full tutorial.

[Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/php/) is a great resource for PHP; their [PHP Roundup](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/40-invaluable-php-tutorials-and-resources/) is particularly helpful. It contains, amongst many other articles, a [CMS example](http://css-tricks.com/1907-php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/) and a screencast for a [PHP login system](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-build-a-login-system-for-a-simple-website/).

Comment: thanks, i have admin system in place and is workin fine :   www.animalswecare.com/admin.php

Comment: I have created a link there adddogs.php this page has some fields related to dogs like there history ,description, photo(move_uploaded_file to move file to server), pagetitle , keywords etc and once user fills all this information it creates a page thr fopen and writes it thr fwrite. But problem comes in fwrite

Comment: You're quite vague in describing your problem. Are you creating a new HTML page for every new dog; do you not have access to a database? This is generally a very bad route to go down and will become very messy _very_ quickly (what if a user wants to edit a page?). (The fwrite problem is _probably_ due a permissions error, though.)

Comment: Yes I want a new page to be created for dog like akita.php , I have access to DB , but I want is 2 things to be done simultaneously i.e. when user clicks on submit to create new page , the script should do 2 things one to add everything to DB and that is working fine and second create a file (that is also working) and insert the code into it and when I try that I use this code:

Comment: fwrite($Handle,$Data) 
$Data holds some html part and a query $file=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$linkf="http://animalswecare.com".$file;    
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM dogs_db WHERE link='$linkf'" or die("error");
but as $linkf is to be given in sinle quotes it ends the rest of the part as we started with single quote

Comment: SO comment threads aren't really ideal for PHP debugging! May I suggest the [PHP Freaks forum](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/)? Make sure you word your question clearly and include an example of the code that's failing.